# sed search replace enrypted string range

Tags: bash, sed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My server's been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

my php based website got infected with malware, which added something like this in the code:

```
<?php eval(base64_decode("DQplcnJvcl9yZXBvcnRpbmcoMCk7DQokcWF6cGxtPWh));
```

Now i want to replace all the "eval(" till its ending braces "));" with space or delete all those occurences,  either with sed or other tools.

i have tried this

```
sed 's/eval\*/ /g' code.php
```

But its not working.

What can be its solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you get infected with malware, don't try to "clean" it. Start over from a backup. Also, just editing this stuff out will last a few minutes or hours before the attacker does it all over again. Find the root cause and make sure it can't happen again on the newly installed machine

Comment: @SvenW: i had backups, but they were old. so the only way is to replace the text.
And i have found the root cause and fixed it, now just need to clean the code.

Comment: IMO, 'the backups were too old' is not a valid answer to solving the problem. Never trust a compromised site/server. You do not know what else got changed. Take your old backups, and edit the code from there.  Learn from this experience. Your only way is a dangerous one, because you don't want to put time in it.

Comment: @LucasKauffman I am already aware of the dangers of it, what i am doing, i cannot tell everything in detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As SvenW says the only real solution to this is to reinstall from a known good backup. You could try

```
sed 's/eval(.*);//' code.php
```

which given your input produces

```
<?php
```

But you don't know what damage has been done to the system so nuke it from orbit and restore from a known good backup - it's the only way to be sure.